# How to use MVC ValidationMessageFor into bootstrap-modal dialog

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi everybody i've a little trouble to ask... I'm trying to get error message into a login bootstrap modal dilog using ValidationMessageFor, but actually isn't working and i don't know why.

This is my login dilog with `Html.BeginForm`

```
<div class="col-xs-2 login-btn">
            <a class="btn pfologin" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bootstrapmodal">
                <span> LOGIN</span>
            </a>

            <!-- Modal dialog -->
            <div class="modal fade bootstrapmodal">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account"))
                    {
                        <div class="modal-content modal-pfo">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>
                                    User:<br />
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    Password:<br />
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </p>
                                <p style="display: flex;">
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(s => s.Privacy, new { @class = "checkbox" }) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Remember me
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-pfo">Cancel</button>
                                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-pfo" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
        </div>...
```

this is the model

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username requested")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password requested")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool Privacy { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel loginModel)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(loginModel.Name))
    {
        return ModelState.AddModelError("Name", loginModel.Name);
    }
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(loginModel.Password))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Password", loginModel.Password);
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

yes I redirect from Login/Post to Index but i don't think this is the problem... thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return RedirectToAction, you lose all your form data (and, therefore, all validation information). Instead of redirecting to Index, return the View with the model that was passed in.

Second, because both properties are marked as Required, you do not need to explicitly check if they are null or empty. The model is already validated *before* it hits your `[HttpPost]` method, based on the attributes you set on the model. If you return the View with this model, your validation messages will appear. This is the most basic implementation, but you can probably get away with:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel loginModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Do work
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    // Else, if not valid, re-render the view with the updated information and display it to the user
    return View(loginModel);
}
```

[More info on validation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation)

Comment: Awesome! Do you mind marking this as the correct answer?

Comment: yeah sorry i didn't knew (: